# Why isn't 'source' working?

Tags: clojure, macros

From the REPL (Cloure 1.4.0) I'm trying to use the `source` macro to show the defintion of my function - but it replies with 'Source not found'

I can use `source` on `source` itself like this (and can see it uses `source-fn`) - but not sure why it doesn't like my `defn x[] "hello"` function definition?

```
user=> (source source)
(defmacro source
  "Prints the source code for the given symbol, if it can find it.
  This requires that the symbol resolve to a Var defined in a
  namespace for which the .clj is in the classpath.

  Example: (source filter)"
  [n]
  `(println (or (source-fn '~n) (str "Source not found"))))
  nil


    user=> (defn x[] "hello")
    #'user/x
    user=> (source x)
    Source not found
    nil
    user=>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`source` can only get the source of functions defined in source files that are available on the classpath. It won't work for functions defined at the REPL.

More precisely, `source` works by looking up the Var named by its argument, checking whether the metadata map on the Var includes source information (for everything is to work `:file` and `:line` keys are needed), looking up the file named in the metadata map, opening the file (as a resource on the classpath), skipping however many lines and finally returning the text behind the next form; see `(source clojure.repl/source-fn)` for details.

So, it'll work for things stored in Vars -- like functions and macros -- defined at top-level in source files that are still present on the classpath. It won't work for things not stored in Vars, as well as those stored in Vars whose backing source is not present on the classpath. The latter case is possible with AOT compilation and things defined at the REPL.

Comment: So is there a way of finding the 'source' of in-REPL defined function (etc) ? For instance if I sat coding at the REPL only, but wanted to save my work (as it currently stands) - would that be possible ?

Answer (score 4):

`source` uses function meta data to find the file that the function was defined in. And then it reads that file to find the function definition, converts it to a String and returns it.

In short, (source source) is doing something like this

```
user> (-> (resolve 'source) 
           meta 
           :file)
"clojure/repl.clj"
```

The meta data for a function defined in the repl will not contain a valid source file.

```
user=> (meta (resolve 'x))
{:arglists ([]), :ns #<Namespace user>, :name x, :column 1, :line 1, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH"}
```

You can see the full workings in the [`source-fn`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.5.1/src/clj/clojure/repl.clj#L134-154) function.

Comment: Thanks - I was torn about which answer to select as accepted as they were both very informative ! Otherwise I would have voted for both! Cheers.